# IO icons from "react icons" not importing

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, importerror, react-icons

I've installed the react-icons module correctly with npm, and everything is working great. I can import icons without any errors, but sadly whenever I try and import an icon with `Io` before it like

IoSettingsSharp

IoSettingsOutline
etc.

simply like:

```js
import { IoSettingsOutline } from 'react-icons/io'
class Home extends Component{
    render(){
        return (
            <div className="app">
                <Link to='/settings'>
                <IoSettingsOutline className="settings-icon"/>
                </Link>
            </div>
       )
    }
};
```

I get the error:

> ./src/Home.js
> Attempted import error: 'IoSettingsOutline' is not exported from 'react-icons/io'.

And what's funny about this is, I've imported every other icon just like this, switching out the name and the ending of `'react-icons/io'`

What is happening and how can I fix this?

Comment: There are different `Ionicons` [versions](https://github.com/react-icons/react-icons#icons). You'll either want to import from [io](https://react-icons.github.io/react-icons/icons?name=io) (which is `Ionicons v4`) or [io5](https://react-icons.github.io/react-icons/icons?name=io5). Click on the links provided to see which icons are supported for each version. In your case, `IoSettingsOutline` comes from `io5`.

Comment: Ok that makes sense!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

as @Matt Carlotta said: "There are different Ionicons Ionicons v4 io5"

try:

```
import { IoSettingsOutline } from 'react-icons/io5'
```

Answer (score 0):

The below import worked for me,

```
import { IoSettingsOutline } from 'react-icons/io5'
```